# Remove posts from two categories in Archive Page

Tags: archives

From Archive Page I want to remove posts from couple of categories, as they have different style formats which will not look good with other category style formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

**Not Tested**

```
add_action("pre_get_posts","my_category_remove");

function my_category_remove($query)
{

if(is_archive()) {
$query->set('category__not_in', array(/*the categories (ID's) you wish not to show, comma separated*/));
}

return $query;
}
```

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: By `/*all the post ids*/` you meant `/*the categories you wish not to show*/` ?

Comment: Yes. You should provide `id`s of all the categories you want to escape. provide the `id`s separated by comma(,).

Comment: **FYI**: When u visit the posts page in admin panel, you won't be able to see the posts from that category so please edit the condition as follows

`if ($query->is_archive && !is_admin()) {}`